# How do substitue sub query as a join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using this query

```
select t.task_id,td.task_detail_id ,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM task_detail tdd where tdd.task_id=t.task_id and  
tdd.status='ACTIVE' ) as total
from task t inner join task_detail td  on td.task_id=t.task_id 
where td.task_id=t.task_id and td.status='ACTIVE' ;
```

Query is running with expected results but i want to change `total column` subquery as a join .

[image: Here is output]

Comment: Move it to the end of the FROM clause (just before WHERE), do LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh OP is already joining to `task_detail`

Comment: Just replace your subquery with `COUNT(*)`, change `inner join` to `left join` and add `group by t.task_id` to the end of the query

Comment: And the join condition is duplicated too...

Comment: @Nick it is not showing those multiple entries related to task_id . However count is okay

Comment: It is not clear from the question whether task_id and task_detail_id are unique. possibly task_id has many task_detail_ids and you may want to show all task_detail_ids for a task with a count of all task_ids - in which case your query is correct(probably) In any case adding sample data and expected output would clarify,

Comment: @P.Salmon see the edits

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this-

```
SELECT 
t.task_id, 
td.task_detail_id, 
COUNT(*)
FROM task t
INNER JOIN task_detail td 
    ON td.task_id = t.task_id AND td.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY t.task_id, td.task_detail_id
```

Comment: returns 1 for taskid 5 , which should be 2 see the edits in image

Comment: May be only 1 task details available with status = active.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you would use window functions

```
select t.task_id, td.task_detail_id,
       count(*) over (partition by t.task_id) as total
from task t inner join
     task_detail td
     on td.task_id = t.task_id 
where td.status = 'ACTIVE' ;
```

In earlier versions, a subquery is recommended, but you can move it to the `from` clause:

```
select t.task_id, td.task_detail_id,
       td2.total
from task t inner join
     task_detail td
     on td.task_id = t.task_id join
     (select count(*) as total
      from task_detail td2
      where td2.status = 'ACTIVE'
      group by td2.task_id
     ) td2
     on td2.task_id = td.task_id
where td.status = 'ACTIVE' ;
```

Comment: what would be the alternative for `5.7.26`